# How to change the Tab Index of MUI Tabs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to change the Tab Index of the MUI Tabs. On clicking the Tab key it has to select First Tab, then the second and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `tabIndex` to the needed level on your `Tab` components, then set their `onFocus` prop to change the `Tabs` `value` prop like this:

```
<Tab
  label="Item One"
  {...a11yProps(0)}
  tabIndex={0}
  onFocus={() => setValue(0)}
/>
```

Or go further by doing a `tabIndex` loop which allow user to cycle on your tabs with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  <Tab
    label="Item One"
    tabIndex={value === 2 ? 3 : 2}
    onFocus={() => setValue(0)}
  />
  <Tab
    label="Item Two"
    tabIndex={2}
    onFocus={() => setValue(1)}
  />
  <Tab
    label="Item Three"
    tabIndex={value === 0 ? 1 : 2}
    onFocus={() => setValue(2)}
  />
</Tabs>
```

This can also be achieved using array index when mapping a list of `<Tab/>` from a set of values.

#### [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-tabs-focus-selection-zzg1s?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use change the current tab programmatically when the user hits the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key by listening to the `keydown` event:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
  setValue(newValue);
};
```

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Tab') {
      setValue((v) => (v === tabData.length - 1 ? 0 : ++v));
    }
  }}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]